# how can I swap Entity Framework connection strings easily when I test on different servers (i.e. different databases)

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, connection-string

how can I swap Entity Framework connection strings easily when I test on different servers (i.e. different databases) - at the moment it is a bit tedious going into the design parameters and trying to swap back and forth each time I change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the ObjectContext constructor that takes a name of the app.config entry and hold several app.config entries for the necessary databases.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a web app? If so you can [use web.config transforms](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx).

Comment: it's a winforms app actually Craig